How to convert image from one custom colormap to another custom colormap Python
I have a video file which is black and white and I want to convert it to a rgb colormapped video. But instead of black to white, a custom colormap as follows - I just want to think of black to white as a series from -1 to 1. And I want to measure the value of every pixel as a "deviation" from the mean value at 0 (most average grey)
Black........Grey........White
   -1...........0............1
Basically, the "most black" or "most white" going closer to 1 or -1 will have a higher value in the colormap and those more closer to 0 "more grey" will have a lower value in the colormap.
For example if the output colormap is Blue to Yellow (notice I have labelled it 0 to 1 only, so its an increasing value)-
Blue.......Green(B+Y).......Yellow
  0.............0.5.............1
So the (modulus of colormap1) value must be converted to (colormap2 values). Once the mapping and modulus operations are applied,  I think the operation of "measuring deviation from grey" can be achieved. That is my objective.
(modulus of colormap1 values) === (colormap2 values)
      ( |-1|..|0|..|1| )      ===    (0...1)
so
Black = |-1| =  1 = Yellow
White =   1  =  1 = Yellow
Grey  =  ~0  =  0 = Blue
It has to be a gradual colormap, not individual colors mapped one by one. I want to use Python only.
I have seen colormap mapping & custom colormap creation in opencv too. However converting one custom colormap of an image to another custom colormap by applying a logical operation is something I wasn't able to find.
(a solution in Python please!)

Your question is interesting, but can be improved by adding code and example images

Just to make sure, in your example you wrote Blue+Yellow = Green but Blue+Yellow will get you White. In case of paintings and dyes you are right but in image/video processing  Green is the primary color, you dont get it by adding two different colors.

Also please correct me if i undertstand anything wrong. You want to first map a grayscale image from [0,255] range to [-1,1] range. Then you want to map the [-1,1] image to color image with a chosen low boundary color and a high boundary color. While mapping to a color any negative value and positive value with same modulus will be mapped to same color.
